# How to create Assault Cube LAN server?

Tags: games, lan

I would like to play Assault Cube with my brother at home an LAN. I can't seem to figure out how. I would like a simple way. Does any one know how to create an Assault Cube Lan Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, install the game:

```
$ sudo apt-get install assaultcube
```

Start the server

```
$ assaultcube-server
```

Run the client

```
$ assaultcube
```

And choice **multiplayer**, have fun!